# How to execute query to a DB from a terminal and store output to a file?

Tags: command-line, sqlite

I want to access this DB and I use this to access the SQLite DB: `sqlite3 .mozilla/firefox/profile_name/places.sqlite`

The query that I want to execute to this DB and store the output in a text file is `SELECT moz_places.url FROM moz_places`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Try `man sqlite`
2. You'll find that `sqlite` expects a syntax such as `sqlite [options] filename [SQL]`
3. Then do this `sqlite [options] filename [SQL] > file_with_results.txt` and the result would be in `file_with_results.txt`

From what you write, I believe you need:

```
sqlite .mozilla/firefox/profile_name/places.sqlite "SELECT moz_places.url FROM moz_places;" > file_with_results.txt
```

Comment: sqlite3 package is required so the above commands with sqlite3 instead of sqlite works